# Validating length of ngrams in varchar field in mySQL

Tags: mysql, varchar, n-gram

I have a column in a table in MySQL which contains ngrams, and I want to validate that each ngram is of the correct length.

For e.g. if the ngram is 'sophisticated hacking scheme' then the number of blanks should be two.

Is there anything in MySQL that would count the blanks? Or can someone suggest a quick SQL fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One that I've used in SQL Server, slightly adapted to using [MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html) is:

```
CHAR_LENGTH(Column) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Column,' ','')
```

That is - what's the length of the column, vs the length of the column if all of the spaces are removed? That *should* give you the number of spaces that were present.

Comment: So I would essentially have length('sophisticated hacking scheme') - length('sophisticatedhackingscheme')?

Comment: As long as there are not extra spaces between the words or at the start/end, of course, but that's probably a safe assumption.

Comment: I think all of my strings have been stripped of leading / trailing spaces.

Comment: Well, it's very curious that when I run query `SELECT * 
FROM Keyword 
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(KeywordText) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(KeywordText,' ','')) = NgramLength` over my database table called Keyword, one of the Keywords is wrong. Why should I be storing 'strauss kahn' as a unigram? Everything else is splendid out of 18736 keywords. column NgramLength stores the supposed length of the ngram.